# JPYLibor fixing during Japanese holiday: negative time error

Tags: python, quantlib

I am using QuantLib 1.7 with the Python interface.

I have constructed the JPY Fixed-Float swap curve following the standard convention. For the swap schedules I have a JointCalendar with Japan and UnitedKingdom. My JPYLibor index has the UK calendar only.

When I set the market date to 2009-May-1, I do a bootstrap using PiecewiseFlatForward with settlement date 2009-May-8 because in the Japan calendar there was a long holiday from 2009-May-4 (monday) to 2009-May-6.

Now, with this bootstraped curve, I try to value a swap that has a floating payment on 2009-May-7. When I try to value it (or compute the amount() function of the next floatingLeg cashflow which has a reset date on 2009-May-5) I get the error message "2nd leg: negative time (-0.00277778) given".

I guess that this is related to the fact that 2009-May-5, which is the London fixing date for value date 2009-May-7, falls on a Japanese holiday?

My swap payments schedules and reset schedule are matching Bloomberg so I am confident in theory is the correct convention. I have read some old posts regarding apparently a similar issue for a US swap, but as far as I understood this was a bug which was corrected around the time of QuantLib 0.9.

Could my problem be related to the same bug or I am not using QuantLib correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the value date for the payment, May 7th, is between today's date and the reference date of the curve.  The fixing needs to be forecast, since it's in the future (the fixing date is on May 5th); but because the curve effectively starts on May 8th, it can't return the May 7th discount which is required to forecast the fixing.

The reason why this doesn't usually happen is that, when the value date is between today and the reference date, the fixing date is usually before today's date and thus the fixing can be loaded from past ones.

In this particular case, the way to make it work would be to create a curve with no settlement days so that its reference date is the same as today's date.  If you then wanted the price as-of May 8th, you'd have to manually adjust the swap NPV for the discount between May 1st and 8th.